# Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee

I'am trying to create data related to the user logged in. I mean, after inserting the login and the password the user will be redirected to the approprate page where he can insert his datas. Here is a part of my managed Bean that allow to create datas.

```
 public void searchEmails() throws Exception {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        System.out.println(session.getAttribute("id"));
        String idCustomer = (String) session.getAttribute("id");
        Customer customer = customerBusinessLocal.findById(idCustomer);
        Data data = dataBusinessLocal.createData(new Date(), email, product, customer);       
       }
```

When i call this method an exception is thrown indicationg that
Internal Exception: `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '7c3ea0c9-6cad-4816-be74-72c453e05756' for key 'PRIMARy'`

while i'am not trying to create a new customer but just get the id of the looged one and associate the data him. I mean in the data Datatable i got the customer's id who is online.

Comment: Does any one have an idea where the problem consists in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.Persist )
private Customer customer;
```

CascadeType.Persist in the entity Data was the cause of my problem. Actually it obliged to persist the customer with data while am trying only to get the customer logged in.